# Trying to get value in array in JS which is outside a function and the function is async

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, sequelize.js

So basically I'm pushing values in an ArrayList named TripsData inside the start function but it's getting empty as soon as I exit the function so I cant exceed further.
where trips are just an array `[1,2,3,4]`

And the code follows...

```
const TripsData = []; // I need to push data in this array
await trips.forEach((trip) => {
    async function start() {
        const url = await TripMedia.findOne({  // i get my url here
            where: { tripID: trip },
        })
            .then((result3) => {
                const url = result3.mediaURL;
                return url;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });

        const subject = await TripDetails.findOne({ // i get my subject here
            where: { tripID: trip },
        })
            .then((result3) => {
                const subject = result3.subject;
                return subject;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        
        TripsData.push({
            tripId: trip,
            mediaURL: url,
            subject: subject,
        });   // The value is getting pushed here
    }
    start();
});
console.log(TripsData) // If i try to get data here its not present

Reply.push({
    "locationId":location,
    "locationName": dict[location],
    "trips": TripsData
}) // so the value of tripsData is like [] only ... how to get data
```

The values are coming to

```
TripsData.push({
    tripId: trip,
    mediaURL: url,
    subject: subject,
});
```

But the value outside of forEach ends it's getting empty?
The question is why so and how to resolve

Thank you in advance for the God Level Help

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the code. The second `console.log` does not run after the `function` is executed, but *before* that, because `start` is `async` and you do not `await` for it. This means that start is added to the [event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) and, even though `trips.forEach` is awaited and executed, the `function` inside it will not be awaited for. So, technically, the second console log is executed after the `forEach`, but before any of the `start` calls finished.

[image]

Comment: even if i make the Reply.push await it doesnt works. and a parent async function to it

Answer (score 0):

**Corrections are needed in your code:** You defined start as async function but while calling it not awaited it, and as await should be called inside async function only, you need to make forEach callback async.

```
await trips.forEach(async (trip) => {
    async function start() {
        
        return TripsData.push({
            tripId: trip,
            mediaURL: url,
            subject: subject,
        });   // The value is getting pushed here
    }
    await start();
});
```

Comment: you are half way correct, the values stay in TripsData after the forEach ends it stills get empty

Comment: i need to get that TripsData to push in Reply

Comment: are you embodying the entire code section in async function? make sure you do that